# How to represent nested values in a csv file? I want to seamlessly load the file into a (nested) python dictionary

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, nested

My first thought is to chain csv files together through references. This will keep the information of each cell simple. A potential problem may arise if the chains become long and finding the correct csv file to edit becomes too complicated.

```
demographics:
    description: This is a description of demographics
        type: string
            value:
                ethnicity:
                        -a
                        -b
                        -c
    node: node801832
    somerandom:
        random1: 201901
        random2: lkk133

A column in popdemographics.csv
demographics        
description.csv     
node.csv        
somerandom.csv      


The csv file referenced by description.csv
description     
This is a description of demographics       
type.csv
```

Comment: CSV is the wrong data format for what you want to store. How about [JSON](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html)?

Comment: CSV is indeed a wrong format for this. You're better off loading this as a dictionary and serializing that dict... either as JSON, protobuf, pickle, etc

Comment: I know it is not a good format, but it must be csv. The information is only available in csvs because it is provided by non-techies and they are not willing to work with any other format.

Comment: Too bad because CSV format doesn't do "nested".

Comment: I think the only option is to use an embedded delimiter in the column values, i.e. something like `food :: vegetable :: bean :: lima`.  However this is quite messy, and if the people providing this data are "non-techies", can you trust them to use this format accurately?

Comment: @JohnGordon I was thinking about flattening the data instead. So the column attribute would be vegetable.bean and the value would be lima.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in csv. You might consider using YAML if you want readability for 'non-techies'